# attempt to get length of a nil value

Tags: roblox

So I'm new to Roblox scripting and I'm making a swordfighting game with a map load system. But the code returns this error **ServerScriptService.GameLoop:13: attempt to get length of a nil value**

Here is my code:

```lua
local config = require(script.Parent.ModuleScript)
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local intermissionCooldown = 20

while true do
    if #game.Players:GetPlayers() < 5 then
        wait(1)
        print("There is not enough players to start the game")
    else
        print("The game is starting soon!")
        wait(intermissionCooldown)
        print("Selecting Map")
        local selectedMap = config.maps[math.random(1, #config.maps)]
        print("Map selected, the round will begin in 5 seconds")
        wait(5)
        local currentMap = selectedMap:Clone()
        currentMap.Name = "Map"
        currentMap.Parent = workspace
    end
end
```

I honestly don't know what to try and I can't find the solution online.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this: `#config.maps`, apparently config does not have a member `.maps`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are trying to get the length of an array, but the object is actually `nil` not an array. And that points to this line : `#config.maps`.

That suggests that `config.maps` doesn't exist, but there's no way for us to really know that because we don't know what you are storing in `local config = require(script.Parent.ModuleScript)`.

So double check `script.Parent.ModuleScript` and make sure that there is a field called `maps` in the table that is being returned.

Comment: config.maps does exist and here is the content of the module script:
 local maps = {
  game.ServerStorage.Maps.Map_Desert, --Index 1
  game.ServerStorage.Maps.Map_Field,
  game.ServerStorage.Maps.Map_Snow
 }
 return maps

Comment: when you say `local config = require(....ModuleScript)`, the thing that is being stored into config is this `{ ...Map_Desert,  ...Map_Field, ...Map_Snow }`. That table does not have a field named `maps`. If you want to get a random map from this array, try something like this : `local selectedMap = config[math.random(1, #config)]`